# How do I prevent a service app from launching its ui activity when it starts?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, wear-os

I want to send a message from a mobile app to a wear app and when the wear app receives it for it to display some UI activity.

I have everything in place and working already for this (the mobile app is using Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage and the wear app is extending WearableListenerService). However my problem is that when I run the wear app the UI appears as it launches, what should I change so that nothing is displayed until the wear app receives the message from the mobile? How do I prevent the Activity's from being created at app launch time?

Manifest:

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".WearMessageListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("WEAR", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class WearMessageListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.i("WEAR", "WearableListenerService:onMessageReceived");
        if( messageEvent.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase( START_ACTIVITY ) ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
            intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            startActivity( intent );
        } else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so I changed the configuration to unclick the launch default activity which did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Changes in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You have set the `LAUNCHER` category in `intent-filter` within your main `Activity` that means this activity can be started from the launcher - on Android Wear it is the place after **pressing on the watchface** to launch the "**Speak now**" screen and scroll down to **Start...**. You will see a list of "launchable" applications there and from your description this is what you also want to avoid.

By removing this `intent-filter` you make sure that user won't be able to launch this `Activity` manually so the only way to launch it is "when the wear app receives the message from the mobile", directly from your code.

Your final manifest should look like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".WearMessageListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

### Changes in Configuration

Android Studio won't allow you to start an Application without the "default Activity" if you had it previously defined. You need to click on "Edit Configuration", then on your "wear" module and select "Do not launch activity" in "General" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good way to do this, but you can send an intent extra from your Service. On the onCreate method of the Activity you can check if you've received any extras, if not, your app was launched as a launcher Activity then you can use finish() to destroy the Activity, otherwise if you received an extra, it means the call came from the Service and you show whatever you have to show.

Comment: So there's no simple way of specifying that the activity shouldn't be launched on app startup? By leaving something out of the manifest for example? I tried leaving out the intent-filter but the build complained there was no default activity. Can I change the type from application to service or something to overcome this?